# Fréchet Derivative Bibliography

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus

Good night,

I'm new studying the Frechet Derivative. I still don't understand the concept of it. My question is...do you have some bibliography about it you can recommend me?

I'd really appreciate your answers.
Thank you.

Comment: Good night? How do you know what time it is?

Comment: @qwr: It's always night somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In English and in book form, I have a couple of old-school suggestions to do.

The clearest and most elegant exposition of the subject that I know about, is still contained in *Differential Calculus*, by Henri Cartan, which you can find in an inexpensive paperback by Dover. It is the most didactic one as well, and even though it takes off quite quickly, it does it at a good pace.

There is, of course, the redoubtable reference *Foundations of Modern Analysis*, by Jean Dieudonné, although it demands much more sophistication on behalf of its reader.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. I just got the Cartan, so I'll begin reading that one.